# How to convert JSON response to Dictionary format in Swift

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

How do I convert this JSON response with hundreds of keys in message, to be able to assign it to a variable type `[AnyHashable: Any]`

**JSON**

```
{
    "content": {
       "message": {
            "greet": "Hello world",
            "error": "There is an error",
            "thanks": "Thank you",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Attempt**

After I've parse the JSON, I've failed to assign `jsonData` to a variable that accept `[AnyHashable: Any]`. I have tried to change `message` type to `[AnyHashable: Any]` but it does not conform to `Decodable`.

```
// Model.swift

struct TestCase: Decodable {
    let content: Content
}

struct Content: Decodable {
    let message: [String: String]
}


// ViewController.swift

private var testVariable: [AnyHashable: Any]

private func loadJson(filename: String) {
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let jsonData = try decoder.decode(TestCase.self, from: data)

            // Problem faced
            testVariable = jsonData // error

        } catch let jsonError {
            print("JsonError: ", jsonError)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your actual code. Show what you tried. Show what problem you are having.

Comment: @samuelkith you can use JSONSerialization jsonObject(with: Data) to convert your json data string to a dictionary.  `let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(json.utf8)) as? [String: [String: [String: String]]]`

Comment: @Sh_Khan, it is a variable inside a library that I am using which has that type.
@LeoDabus, and how would it looks like if I want to use `Decodable`

Comment: @Sh_Khan json data is an utf8 String. You can't cast a String to a Dictionary

Comment: `testVariable = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [AnyHashable: Any] ?? [:]`

Comment: @samuelkith  it isn't clear whether you need to assign the whole decoded object or message only

Comment: @Sh_Khan the whole decoded object, so ideally I want it to be in the format of `testVariable = [content: [message: [ "key": "value" ] ] ]`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have both.

Either you want to parse the JSON with `Decodable` then you have to declare `testVariable` as

```
private var testVariable : TestCase?
```

Or you want to keep `testVariable` as `[AnyHashable: Any]` then delete the structs and decode the JSON with traditional `JSONSerialization`

```
//print(s)
struct TestCase: Decodable {
    let content: Content
}

struct Content: Decodable {
    let message: [String: String]
}
```

```
// ViewController.swift

private var testVariable = [AnyHashable:Any]()

private func loadJson(filename: String) {
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            testVariable = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [AnyHashable: Any] ?? [:]

        } catch {
            print("JsonError: ", error)
        }
    }
}
```